# What was Cynthia's (the dead girl) role in the drug operations in 22 Jump Street?

Tags: plot-explanation, 22-jump-street

In the movie *22 Jump Street*, Jencko & Smidth go again as undercover cops at a college where a girl named Cynthia has died. Early on, they have a photo of
Cynthia & the drug dealer. Later on they think that Cynthia, in the photo, might actually be the dealer after all. 
In the end, it was

> Cynthia's roommate

who was the mastermind behind this drug empire in the college.

So, what role did Cynthia play in the operation? Also, why
did she die? If it is mentioned in the movie, I must have totally missed it while I fell of the chair laughing for most of the movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**what role did Cynthia play in the operation?**

Cynthia is a student at MC state. She's a drug addict and also a dealer and she gets the drugs from her roommate Mercedes.

**why did she die?**

The reason was mentioned at the beginning of the movie.

> She was a student at MC state.
>
> She took some whyphy,
>
> got locked out of her dorm,
>
> ended up falling off the roof.
>
> And now she's dead.

**who was the mastermind behind this drug empire in the college.**

It's Mercedes, she has a connection with drug mafia (I think it's her uncle.). It's shown towards the ending of the movie, that's how she got the drugs and made Cynthia to deal them.

I hope this clear things up for you.