# Why is Zook on the photo with Cynthia

Tags: plot-explanation, 22-jump-street

In 22 Jump Street, Zook is caught with his tatoo on a picture with Cynthia. Since we know that Zook is not the dealer and neither is Cynthia, why is he on the photo with Cynthia?

Comment: As far as I remember, Cynthia WAS the dealer..

Comment: Just asked the question y'day about what was the role of Cynthia in the drug operations http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28545/what-was-cynthias-the-dead-girl-role-in-the-drug-operations-in-22-jump-street She was the dealer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He was purchasing the drugs from her, not selling them to her, as the cops had originally thought.